# Heegner numbers, still UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I just found out about [Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) but there is something I quite don't understand about them :
As I understand it, they are numbers D, such that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-D}]$ is still a UFD, correct?
For instance, 2 is a Heegner number. But why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ an UFD?

Don't I have $3 = (1-\sqrt{-2})(1+\sqrt{-2})$ for example (and these elements are prime?)?

**Edit**

A better example to show 2 decomposition would have been :
$2 \times 3 = 6 = (2-\sqrt{-2})(2+\sqrt{-2})$

Comment: $3$ isn't prime. Well, not in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ anyway.

Comment: To expand on the other comment: the very fact you can write $3$ as a product means that $3$ is _not_ a prime!

Comment: Is there a way to quickly know if an element is a unit or if it is a prime?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is there?

Comment: Because for the moment I am just saying number = $\alpha \beta$ and so $N(number) = N(\alpha) N(\beta)$ and I check that this means that either $\alpha$, either $\beta$ is $\pm 1$ which are the only units (if $d \neq 1$)

Answer (score 1):

$R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a Euclidean domain (and so a UFD). The Euclidean function
is $N(a+b\sqrt{-2})=|a+b\sqrt{-2}|^2=a^2+2b^2$.

To confirm this is a Euclidean function, one has to prove that if $\alpha$,
$\beta\in R$ with $\beta\ne0$ there is $\gamma\in R$ with $N(\alpha-\gamma\beta)
<N(\beta)$. To prove this, write $\alpha/\beta=x+y\sqrt{-2}$ with $x$, $y$ real,
and take $\gamma=r+s\sqrt{-2}$ with $r$, $s$ nearest integers to $x$, $y$.